# Disallow a Cobrand in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

this is my first question here but I am using this forum for a lot of time to solve a lot of problems that I had during the time , but now  I cant find any information to help me in this problem.

I have several cobrands that have affiliate content so I cant control at all the content on that as they are white labels and I only set the cname on them. Because now google looks like is considering cobrands a whole of the root page.

I need to deindex this cobrands to eliminate low content report; I am trying to contact the affiliate managers but .... they are very slow(some of them).

I am looking for a way to disallow in robots.txt this sites : http://cobrand.domain.com ...

any help much appreciate it.
Txs

Comment: If you've been using the site for some time, you should know that people here value having as much specific information as possible about your problem more highly than kind words. I'm not clear who is running these sites: you on behalf of the "cobrands", or them on behalf of you? And what exactly are you seeing on Google that you don't want? ("considering cobrands a whole of the root page" doesn't make a lot of sense to me I'm afraid)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disallow crawling of URLs whose host is `http://cobrand.example.com/`, you need to place a text file `robots.txt` at the document root of that host: `http://cobrand.example.com/robots.txt`

The following content would block everything for every polite bot:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am sorry but is nothing to hide, this is an affiliates with a whitelabel cobrand so of course I have no access on the root or at the files, if is a whitelabel, I am not having control over the content ....I only have the cnames set. So is not too much info available. I want to disallow them or noindex them because I have the impression google consider also cobrands duplicate sites and can penalize me as domain for this duplicates...

Comment: @user2824312: If you don’t have control over the host, you can’t block anything for search engines. You need at least one of these permissions: a) send HTTP headers, b) edit HTML, c) upload a specific file to the document root (would only work for some search engines, though), d) change the robots.txt.